# How to make PHP web application work online and offline?

Tags: php, database, web, web-applications

I am new into web development. I have PHP web application which I created using some Rapid Development Tool. For now I can run it on the server with online database and as well i can run it on my local machine with local database (offline, using XAMPP).

The question is: How to make web PHP application that will be:

- stored locally
- be able to easily update somehow on different devices
- will work with online database when internet is here. Once internet is not here, database will be switched to local one.
- databases will be synchronized as well

Is there any software that can handle all of this? Or should I do it manually? Since I am new here, I have completely no ideas on how to realize that.

Comment: This might cause a lot of trouble, as you need to synchronize the databases. This involves generating unique identifiers per environment and the sync process itself, probably coupled with a process to resolve problems (eg. an entity was updated on both systems - what should the sync do now?). As this is way to broad to be answered here: are you sure you want to take that path?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But customer doesnt want to listen and wants me to implement that feature of offline app. In case if they work from jungles (no joke)

Comment: I agree with Nico. This is far from trivial to solve because of conflicting states in your local and remote database. In a typical use case PHP runs on a server and is always connected to its data sources by making them failover. In case the remote database is not reachable, PHP will respond with an error code. If you still want to serve content you can use caching mechanisms to display the last known state, but keeping changes and applying them after the db is reachable again is nothing you want to support.

Comment: “Is there any software that can handle all of this? Or should I do it manually?” I am fairly certain there is no PHP library or tool supporting this, because dealing with out of sync state is very specific to your data and how you want to reconcile. I don’t think you should do it manually, but if you need to have this, it is the only way to go. Just be aware that in my opinion you are setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: Regarding to conflicting databases, i got solution that in offline mode, users are not able to delete or change anything from it, but only add new records. Unique keys are generated with the use of unique ID on each user and  timestamps, so that they would never conflict. Anyways, I still consider that as not a big issue. Just wondering of what are tools or software I can use in this case. @NicoHaase  and dbrumann

Comment: "Just wondering of what are tools or software I can use in this case" - why not use PHP? Also, plan for a difficult deployment process. How would you ensure that all clients receive the latest updates? You should avoid that different states of your software exist (eg you dont' want to store data in your offline app that you cannot sync to the online database due to missing or added columns)

Comment: What happens when your remote database comes back? Even if locally no entries can be deleted or changed, you still have to check all existing entries (field by field) if they changed remotely to make your local database up to date, which means your PHP application needs to do a full database sync on each reconnect, ideally in the background. When you have multiple clients they do the same, write their data to remote and then who says your local data is still in sync, so you start it again. Your app is always handling all data all the time, it’s a nightmare!

Comment: If you want a feasible solution, write a local app where you can trigger synchronization with remote once you have a stable connection, e.g. while still in the office and when you are back from the jungle, by pressing a button. It will still take long to synchronize and will still be messy, but at least you keep the mess out of the running application.

Comment: Alright, will try to do "synchronize on click" and will use PHP to do so. Thank you guys! @dbrumann and Nico